# Boost JSON parser and ip address

Tags: c++, json, boost

I want to get the child nodes of node which is having ip address. 
Below is the reference JSON format and code i am using.

```
{  
"nodes":{  
  "192.168.1.1": {  
     "type":"type1",         
     "info":"info1",
     "error":"error1"
  },
  "192.168.1.2":{  
     "type":"type2",         
     "info":"info2",
     "error":"error2"
  },
  "test":{  
     "type":"type2",         
     "info":"info2",
     "error":"error2"
  }
 }
}
```

Below is the reference code to read above json data.

```
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
ptree pt;
std::string ttr("test.json");
read_json(ttr, pt);

BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("nodes"))
{
    std::string key_ = v.first.data();
    std::string val_ = v.second.data();        

    boost::optional< ptree& > child = pt.get_child_optional( "nodes.192.168.1.1" );
    if( !child )
    {
        std::cout << "Child Node Missing.............." << std::endl; //Always shows Node Missing. How to deal with "." as key ?
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Child Node Not Missing.............." << std::endl;        
}
```

Can you please suggest how to read the child if node contains "." ( ip address ) ? Here "nodes.test" will work but "nodes.192.168.1.1" will not work because it contains "." as string ? How to get it working ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/property_tree/accessing.html):

> To use a separator character other than default `'.'`, you need to construct a path object explicitly. The path type for a `ptree` is a `string_path` instantiation, so the easiest way to refer to it is `ptree::path_type`. This way you can use trees that have dots in their keys[.]

In your case:

```
boost::optional< ptree& > child = pt.get_child_optional(ptree::path_type("nodes/192.168.1.1", '/'));
```